# state of app after 2 rotations

Tags: android, screen-rotation, onsaveinstancestate, onrestoreinstancestate

i have been through this documentation regarding the topic save a state before the foreground activity will be destroyed...

and everything works really good now (after a device rotation), but when i rotate my device again after a rotation, i will loose my data again :(

here is my code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final MainActivity activity = this;
    activity.setTitle("Cow Counter");

    TextView QntyResultField = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    QntyResultField.setText(Integer.toString(cowQnty));
}

// invoked when the activity may be temporarily destroyed, save the instance state here
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("qnty", cowQnty);
}

// How we retrieve the data after app crash...
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    //cowQnty = savedInstanceState.getInt("qnty");

    TextView QntyResultField = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    QntyResultField.setText("Cows: "+Integer.toString(savedInstanceState.getInt("qnty")));
}
```

I think the solution will be maybe to implement a check if an instance state was already restored before...

i have tried then this here:

```
if(savedInstanceState.getInt("qnty") != 0){
    TextView QntyResultField = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    QntyResultField.setText("Cows: "+Integer.toString(savedInstanceState.getInt("qnty")));
}
```

buit then my inital part in my onCreate() method will write a zero in my result field

```
TextView QntyResultField = findViewById(R.id.textView);
QntyResultField.setText(Integer.toString(cowQnty));
```

Could anyone tell me if I am close to the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a variable called `cowQnty` to store the value that is then saved in the bundle for your `onSaveInstanceState` as `outState.putInt("qnty", cowQnty);`, then when you restore it in `onRestoreInstanceState` you only set the `TextView`'s value to the retrieved value and do not update the value for `cowQnty`.

How do you expect then to save an empty field again? There are two solutions to this;

Firstly, if `cowQnty` is not a sizeable amount and you do not mind using a tad of RAM, make `cowQnty` a `static` field and it will persist the data without needing to save it in a `Bundle` at all.

Secondly, just set `cowQnty`'s value once again when you restore your state (why did you comment it out??), like so:

```
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    cowQnty = savedInstanceState.getInt("qnty");

    TextView QntyResultField = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    QntyResultField.setText("Cows: "+Integer.toString(savedInstanceState.getInt("qnty")));
}
```

Comment: shame on me :( 
i was thinking and thinking and thinking.... its absol. clear >> i have to set my qnty everyt time, when I restore my state #ahhhhhh THANK YOU SO MUCH!